# Flip a RelativeLayout onClick

Tags: java, android, android-layout, flipview

I have a `RelativeLayout` in which there is inside another `RelativeLayout` I want flip the last layout for entire if possible but i i don't know if possible. The layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:background="#e7e9e8"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:gravity="center|top"    
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:background="@layout/background_card"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btns"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ff888888"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

         <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/photo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/list" 
             /> 

    <!-- for weather -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageviewMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@layout/background_card"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


         <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/citybox"
                    android:textColor="#63b875"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="City"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:textSize="23sp" />
         <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_forecast_info"
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/clear"    
                    android:layout_below="@+id/citybox"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_height="95dp" />

        <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/temperaturenow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageview_forecast_info"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:text="@string/ricercacondition"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:textColor="#ff888888"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
        <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/temperatura"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:text=""
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_forecast_info"
                    android:textColor="#ff888888"
                    android:textSize="75sp" />

        <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/maxmin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#FFBB33"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/temperatura"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_forecast_info"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- end weather layout --> 


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I need flip the part of `weather` layout. I saw this: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html But really i can't understand how could i do in my case. Infact, the first question is; can i flip a layout instead for example a `ImageView` or something else? And if yes, how? I have an `Activity` and not a `Fragment`. Can i do it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go for the [3D Flip Animation](https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/) in android. The view transition animations in Android are very limited. One particular omission is the 3D flip transition that is common in iOS.

Also check for the [FlipCard Animation](http://2cupsoftech.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/3d-flip-between-two-view-or-viewgroup-on-android/)

Comment: So, you are telling me that should works but it's not raccomanded because limited?

Answer (score 0):

Just to notify that I've developed a new library [FlipView](https://github.com/davideas/FlipView) that includes basic flip animation and extends `ViewFlipper`. I mean a fully customizable library where you will be able to swap any kind of views and layouts with any kind of animation and shapes you desire (and much more), included the Gmail image flipping.

Please have a look.